# Converting query including MySQL CONCAT function with three parameters to DQL Query (two parameters)

Tags: symfony, dql

I'm trying to convert this working MySQL query to DQL query, but I'm facing problem in using the CONCAT function (maybe) in DQL. As I know the CONCAT function in DQL can accept only **two parameters**, but I need three parameters and after searching I found this solution - **NESTED CONCAT**:

**MySQL query needed to be converted to DQL:**

```
SET @new_booking_pickup_date = '2016-04-01';
SET @new_booking_pickup_time = '12:00:00';
SET @new_booking_return_date = '2016-05-01';
SET @new_booking_return_time = '13:00:00';

SELECT * FROM Reservation WHERE NOT ( 

CONCAT(@new_booking_pickup_date,' ',@new_booking_pickup_time) > CONCAT(return_date,' ',return_time) + INTERVAL 0 DAY 
OR 
CONCAT(@new_booking_return_date,' ',@new_booking_return_time) < CONCAT(pickup_date,' ',pickup_time) + INTERVAL 0 DAY
);
```

**here is the DQL solution what I'm trying with *NESTED CONCAT*:**

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery(
        'SELECT id, licensePlate,

        (SELECT car1.model FROM AppBundle:Car car1 WHERE car1.id = car.id) AS model_id,
        (SELECT car2.brand FROM AppBundle:Car car2 WHERE car2.id = car.id) AS brand_id,

        (SELECT carmodel.model FROM AppBundle:CarModel carmodel WHERE carmodel.id = model_id) AS model_name,
        (SELECT carbrand.brand FROM AppBundle:CarBrand carbrand WHERE carbrand.id = brand_id) AS brand_name

          FROM AppBundle:Car car WHERE IDENTITY(car.id) NOT IN (

            SELECT IDENTITY(reservation.car) FROM AppBundle:Reservation reservation WHERE NOT (

              CONCAT(CONCAT(:pickupDate, \' \'),:pickupTime) > CONCAT(CONCAT(reservation.returnDate, \' \'),reservation.returnTime) + INTERVAL 0 DAY 
           OR 
              CONCAT(CONCAT(:returnDate, \' \'),:returnTime) < CONCAT(CONCAT(reservation.pickupDate, \' \'),reservation.pickupTime) + INTERVAL 0 DAY

           )


           )'
    )
    ->setParameter('pickupDate', $pickupDate)
    ->setParameter('returnDate', $returnDate)
    ->setParameter('returnTime', $returnTime)
    ->setParameter('pickupTime', $pickupTime)
    ->getResult();
```

**Here is the result after execution of the DQL query - *Exception!!!*:**

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 831: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got '0'
```

**EDIT: Tried this DQL query without any success by proposal of @Alvin Bunk:**

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            "SELECT car.id AS car_id,

            (SELECT IDENTITY(car1.model) FROM AppBundle:Car car1 WHERE car1.id = car.id) AS model_id,
            (SELECT IDENTITY(car2.brand) FROM AppBundle:Car car2 WHERE car2.id = car.id) AS brand_id,

            (SELECT carmodel.model FROM AppBundle:CarModel carmodel WHERE carmodel.id = model_id) AS model_name,
            (SELECT carbrand.brand FROM AppBundle:CarBrand carbrand WHERE carbrand.id = brand_id) AS brand_name

              FROM AppBundle:Car car WHERE IDENTITY(car.id) NOT IN (

                SELECT IDENTITY(reservation.car) FROM AppBundle:Reservation reservation WHERE NOT (

                  CONCAT(CONCAT(:pickupDate,' '),:pickupTime) > CONCAT(CONCAT(reservation.returnDate,' '),reservation.returnTime) + INTERVAL 0 DAY 
               OR 
                  CONCAT(CONCAT(:returnDate,' '),:returnTime) < CONCAT(CONCAT(reservation.pickupDate,' '),reservation.pickupTime) + INTERVAL 0 DAY

               )


               )"
        )
        ->setParameter('pickupDate', $pickupDate)
        ->setParameter('returnDate', $returnDate)
        ->setParameter('returnTime', $returnTime)
        ->setParameter('pickupTime', $pickupTime)
        ->getResult();
```

Here I'm using double quotes around the main query and single quotes in **CONCAT** function. I get the same error message:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 849: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got '0'
```

**EDIT:**
I'm starting to think the problem is coming from the **NESTED CONCAT** function, but I tested it in the console and it's working perfect - here is the result:

```
php app/console doctrine:query:dql "SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(car.licensePlate,' '),car.deposit) FROM AppBundle:Car car"

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    string(10) "B0001HA 20"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    string(10) "B0002HA 20"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    string(10) "B0003HA 30"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    string(10) "B0004HA 40"
  }
}
```

**The solution:**

The problem was in (+ INTERVAL 0 DAY) - it's not supported by DQL, in this case I don't even need it because my fields are already of type DATE and TIME.

```
public function getCarsNotInRange($pickupDate, $pickupTime, $returnDate, $returnTime)
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                "
                SELECT car.id, car.licensePlate,

                (SELECT IDENTITY(car1.model) FROM AppBundle:Car car1 WHERE car1.id = car.id) AS model_id,
                (SELECT IDENTITY(car2.brand) FROM AppBundle:Car car2 WHERE car2.id = car.id) AS brand_id,

                (SELECT carmodel.model FROM AppBundle:CarModel carmodel WHERE carmodel.id = model_id) AS model_name,
                (SELECT carbrand.brand FROM AppBundle:CarBrand carbrand WHERE carbrand.id = brand_id) AS brand_name

                  FROM AppBundle:Car car WHERE car.id NOT IN 
                  (
                    SELECT IDENTITY(reservation.car) FROM AppBundle:Reservation reservation WHERE NOT 
                        (
                          CONCAT(CONCAT(:pickupDate, ' '),:pickupTime) > CONCAT(CONCAT(reservation.returnDate, ' '),reservation.returnTime)
                     OR 
                          CONCAT(CONCAT(:returnDate, ' '),:returnTime) < CONCAT(CONCAT(reservation.pickupDate, ' '),reservation.pickupTime)
                      )
                  )

        ")
            ->setParameter('pickupDate', $pickupDate)
            ->setParameter('returnDate', $returnDate)
            ->setParameter('returnTime', $returnTime)
            ->setParameter('pickupTime', $pickupTime)
            ->getResult();
    }
```

Comment: You're missing a close parenthesis

Comment: I can't figure out what exactly is the problem

Comment: I just gave you the answer. It's a syntax error because you're missing a closing parenthesis

Comment: Still can't find the syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution:**

The problem was in (+ INTERVAL 0 DAY) - it's not supported by DQL, in this case I don't even need it because my fields are already of type DATE and TIME.

```
public function getCarsNotInRange($pickupDate, $pickupTime, $returnDate, $returnTime)
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                "
                SELECT car.id, car.licensePlate,

                (SELECT IDENTITY(car1.model) FROM AppBundle:Car car1 WHERE car1.id = car.id) AS model_id,
                (SELECT IDENTITY(car2.brand) FROM AppBundle:Car car2 WHERE car2.id = car.id) AS brand_id,

                (SELECT carmodel.model FROM AppBundle:CarModel carmodel WHERE carmodel.id = model_id) AS model_name,
                (SELECT carbrand.brand FROM AppBundle:CarBrand carbrand WHERE carbrand.id = brand_id) AS brand_name

                  FROM AppBundle:Car car WHERE car.id NOT IN 
                  (
                    SELECT IDENTITY(reservation.car) FROM AppBundle:Reservation reservation WHERE NOT 
                        (
                          CONCAT(CONCAT(:pickupDate, ' '),:pickupTime) > CONCAT(CONCAT(reservation.returnDate, ' '),reservation.returnTime)
                     OR 
                          CONCAT(CONCAT(:returnDate, ' '),:returnTime) < CONCAT(CONCAT(reservation.pickupDate, ' '),reservation.pickupTime)
                      )
                  )

        ")
            ->setParameter('pickupDate', $pickupDate)
            ->setParameter('returnDate', $returnDate)
            ->setParameter('returnTime', $returnTime)
            ->setParameter('pickupTime', $pickupTime)
            ->getResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using double quotes around the main query instead. I think it sees "\" as a next line and gives that error.

Updated the below:

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery(
        "SELECT id, licensePlate,
        (SELECT car1.model FROM AppBundle:Car car1 WHERE car1.id = car.id) AS model_id,
        (SELECT car2.brand FROM AppBundle:Car car2 WHERE car2.id = car.id) AS brand_id,
        (SELECT carmodel.model FROM AppBundle:CarModel carmodel WHERE carmodel.id = model_id) AS model_name,
        (SELECT carbrand.brand FROM AppBundle:CarBrand carbrand WHERE carbrand.id = brand_id) AS brand_name
        FROM AppBundle:Car car
          WHERE IDENTITY(car.id) NOT IN (
            SELECT IDENTITY(reservation.car) FROM AppBundle:Reservation reservation WHERE NOT (
              CONCAT(:pickupDate, \' \', :pickupTime) > CONCAT(reservation.returnDate, \' \', reservation.returnTime) + INTERVAL 0 DAY 
           OR 
              CONCAT(:returnDate, \' \',:returnTime) < CONCAT(reservation.pickupDate, \' \',reservation.pickupTime) + INTERVAL 0 DAY
           )
           )"
    )
    ->setParameter('pickupDate', $pickupDate)
    ->setParameter('returnDate', $returnDate)
    ->setParameter('returnTime', $returnTime)
    ->setParameter('pickupTime', $pickupTime)
    ->getResult();
```

Try it again!

Comment: I updated the question - still didn't work. I'm thinking the problem is coming from CONCAT function. I tested the CONCAT function in the console with success it's concatenating right.

Comment: I updated my code and removed the inside concat. maybe that's the problem - try it out and see if it works!

Comment: Not working again. As little as I know the DQL CONCAT function didn't work with three parameters, it will accept only two. That's why I'm using nested CONCAT. See my working console DQL query with NESTED CONCAT in the EDIT.